# Custom order of articles from WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

How might I be able to order the Wordpress articles received from a loop in the following order:

1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10

Using a query similar to this:

```
    $article_feed_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'offset' => 1,
    ));
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where is the `1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10` coming from and do you want them ordered in ascending, numerical order?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the solution for set the custom order.

step1: Please add this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/.
step2: go to setting and check your post type that you want to change the order.
step3: go to your post and drag and drop the post from admin. 
step4: add this below code in your template 



 $article_feed_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
    ));
```

Comment: Hello, I actually found a different solution that was better for my needs (ie no plugins). Had a nested loop so the logic went: 

Loop 1
Content from Loop 1
Loop 2 (offset by amount set by variable in options)
Content from Loop 2
End of Loop 2
End of Loop 1

But thanks regardless